# How to automatically add semicolons in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ always lets me know when I forget a `;` at the end of a declaration or function. Is there any way to get it to add one automatically when it sees that I have missed one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it might be <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd> you're looking for. <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd> on a mac.

Comment: That add ones with manual change of keys, not automatically.